# Proving $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos\frac{2\pi k}{n}=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, trigonometric-series

I want to prove that the below equation can be held.

> $$\sum_{ k=1 }^{ n  } \cos\left(\frac{  2 \pi k }{  n  } \right) =0, \qquad n>1 $$

Firstly I tried to check the equation with small values of $n$

$$  \text{As } n=2 $$

$$  \cos\left(\frac{  2 \pi \cdot 1   }{  2  } \right) + \cos\left(\frac{  2 \pi \cdot 2   }{  2   } \right)  $$

$$ = \cos\left(\pi\right)  + \cos\left(2 \pi\right)    $$

$$ = -1+ 1 =0  ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{Obvious}  $$

But

$$  \text{As}~~ n=3  $$

$$  \cos\left(\frac{  2 \pi \cdot  1   }{  3   } \right) +\cos\left(\frac{  2 \pi  \cdot  2   }{  3   } \right) + \cos\left(\frac{  2 \pi  \cdot  3   }{  3   } \right)  $$

$$ = \cos\left(\frac{  2 \pi  }{  3  } \right) + \cos\left(\frac{  4 \pi  }{  3  } \right) + \cos\left( 2\pi \right)  $$

$$ = \cos\left(\frac{  2 \pi  }{  3  } \right) + \cos\left(\frac{  4 \pi  }{  3  } \right) + 1  =?$$

What formula(s) or property(s) can be used to prove the equation?

Comment: This may be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4136552/limit-of-series-involving-sum-of-cosines-lim-n-to-infty-sum-k-0n-co

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro :  this question has come up many times going back to the start of the site...

Comment: And the last time it came up was 6 hours ago... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4170389/summation-from-0-to-n-of-cosk-n2-pi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\cos(\frac{2\pi k}{n})=\operatorname{Re}\left(\sum_{k=1}^ne^{\frac{2\pi ki}{n}}\right).$$
Consider the sum
$$\sum_{k=1}^ne^{\frac{2\pi ki}{n}}=\sum_{k=1}^n(e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}})^k$$
and use the fact that
$$1+\sum_{k=1}^n r^k =\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$$
to show it's zero.

Comment: I'm trying this way.

Comment: I've been stuck of combinating the 2nd and 3rd equations..

Comment: You have $$r=\operatorname{exp}\left(\frac{2\pi i}{n}\right).$$ Try moving the $1$ on the LHS over and combining it with quotient on the RHS before using the formula.

Comment: I finally solved! Thx!

Answer (score 5):

Your sum is the sum of the real parts of the $n$th roots of the unity. That is, they are the roots of the polynomial $z^n-1$. The sum of the roots is equal to the coefficient of $z^{n-1}$ by Vieta's formulas, hence it is zero.

Comment: I originally thought of the geometric series approach, but this is very slick!

Comment: @user580918 When I was writing the answer, I was going to use the symmetry of the roots, but all of a sudden I realized that I could use Vieta's formulas..

Answer (score 0):

The cosines are the $x$-coordinates of points on the unit circle equally spaced around the origin.  Since the average $x$ value is zero, it follows that the sum of the $x$ values is also zero.